# How to make a div the size of the scrollable window, not screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When the screen is full screen the elements are ok, but when i make the screen smaller, or the content of the div is bigger than the div itself they just go out of it. How do I make the div the size of the whole scrollable window, or maybe make the div fit its content without spilling.

```css
.main {
  vertical-align: top;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 80vh;
  opacity: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -45%);
}

.main .year2018 .allMembers {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Set it to `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` in JavaScript.

Comment: Seeing all the relevant HTML and CSS in a snippet would make this far simpler to diagnose and provide an answer.

Comment: @Wet_Pantz you can try width:100vw and overflow-x:scroll(If required) for the wrapper. I hope, It may help.

Comment: @ScottMarcus how do i make it 80% of it though?

Comment: please provide the HTML codes aswell. giving you a awnser without seing the whole structure and code it is makes it hard to udnerstand what you currently have and trying to achieve with it.

Comment: `window.innerWidth * .8`?